# Mystery 2x14 grey brick - cannot find instructions with this piece mentioned

Tags: part-identification

I have a bunch of LEGO bricks from the years 1975 - 2016. There are a lot of obscure pieces in my collection, but this piece is so obscure that I have no idea what it goes to. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: btw i have found a second 1 they have a 1 and a 2 on the bottom

Comment: Does it have LEGO logo on the bottom?

Comment: yes, and they both have "a 1" and "a 2" on the inside.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is **item no 812**

- Train Level Crossing Center Rail Cap Insert 
  2 x 14 x 2/3

made for item no 813, the railroad crossing.

[image: no813]

(source: bricklink)

It replaces the 12V straight insert (i.e. it closes the middle gap) when using a 4.5V train system.